# Pythonic way to obtain a dictionary from a set

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have set, `some_set = {'A', 'B', 'C'}`
I'm looking to turn this into a dictionary like so:
`my_dict = {'A':{'B','C'}, 'B':{'A','C'}, 'C':{'A','B'}}`
ie a dictionary of sets, where every key is mapped to a set having all elements from the original set except the key itself.

What I have right now:

```py
for letter_1 in some_set
    for letter_2 in some_set:
        if letter_1 not in my_dict.keys():
            my_dict[letter_1] = set()
        if letter_2 != letter_1:
            my_dict[letter_1].add(letter_2)
```

What I'm looking for:
Is this the best way to do it? Would there be a more pythonic way to achieve what I want?

Comment: `if letter_1 not in my_dict.keys()` is not really necessary,

Comment: The resulting (value) set is easy to calculate from the key and the original set. Why do you need a dictionary?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> some_set = {'A', 'B', 'C'}
>>> my_dict = {k: some_set - {k} for k in some_set}
{'A': {'B', 'C'}, 'B': {'A', 'C'}, 'C': {'A', 'B'}}
>>>
```

Comment: Alternatively, `{k: some_set.difference(k) for k in some_set}`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `...difference([k])`. Yours works accidentally because `k` is a string of length 1.

Comment: @Ayush What should it do in that case?

Comment: @AKX Actually, nevermind. That's perhaps better suited for a different question. Great job, thanks !